# Wrong SQL syntax, cannot find it myself

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

i have stared myself blind at this. And need some help to locate the error.

html:

```
        <b>Navn:</b> 
        <input type="text" name="navn" id="navn">

        </br>
        </br>

        <b>K&oslash;n:</b>
        <input type="radio" name="køn" value="mand" id="radio">Mand
        <input type="radio" name="køn" value="kvinde">Kvinde

        </br>
        </br>

        <b>Alder:</b> 
        <select name="alder" id="selecta">
        <option value="blank"></option>
        <option value="10til15">10 til 15 &aring;r</option>
        <option value="15til20">15 til 20 &aring;r</option>
        <option value="20til25">20 til 25 &aring;r</option>
        <option value="25til30">25 til 30 &aring;r</option>     
        </select>

        </br>
        </br>

        <b>V&aelig;gt:</b>  
        <select name="vægt" id="selectv">
        <option value="blank">Vægt</option> 
        <option value="30til40">30 til 40 kg</option>
        <option value="40til50">40 til 50 kg</option>
        <option value="50til60">50 til 60 kg</option>
        <option value="60til70">60 til 70 kg</option>       
        </select>

        </br>
        </br>

        <b>B&aelig;lte:</b>
        <select name="bælte" id="selectb">
        <option value="blank">vægt</option>
        <option value="hvid">Hvid</option>
        <option value="grøn">Gr&oslash;n</option>
        <option value="blå">Bl&aring;</option>
        <option value="sort">Sort</option>      
        </select>
```

php:

```
$navn = $_POST['navn'];
$køn = $_POST['køn'];
$alder = $_POST['alder'];
$vægt = $_POST['vægt'];
$bælte = $_POST['bælte'];

$con = mysql_connect("...", "...", "...") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";

mysql_select_db("...", $con) or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to Database<br />";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Tilmeldinger 
(column 2, column 3, column 4, column 5, column 6)
VALUES ($navn, $køn, $alder, $vægt, $bælte)") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tilmeldinger ORDER BY column 3, column 4, column 5, column 6") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close;

echo "Tak for din tilmelding! Du bliver viderstillet om et kort øjeblik";

header("Refresh: 5; URL=http://www.casperwmn.dk/tilmelding.php");
exit; }
```

Im getting the output:

```
Connected to MySQL
Connected to Database
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column 2, column 3, column 4, column 5, column 6) VALUES (Casper, mand, 20til25,' at line 2
```

I have been over the valuable &vægt but i can't seem to locate what is wrong?

In advance, thanks!

Comment: What is the table structure?  Are your columns really named `column 2`, `column 3`?

Comment: Do your columns really have spaces in them? If so you must backquote them `\`column 1`\`,

Comment: You can't have spaces in your column names. You need the actual column names not names like "column 2".  Also the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use http://php.net/PDO -- Edit: You can have spaces in column names but you need to surround them with backticks. Still you should name your columns descriptively.

Comment: I'd say `column 2` is not a valid column name...

Comment: I think its the spaces...

Comment: Im embarresed. Rookie mistake, it was indeed the column name that was wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL statements, the column names cannot have spaces unless you quote them.  E.g:

```
INSERT INTO (`column 2`, `column 3`, ...) VALUES ( ... )
```

Likewise in the SELECT, the column names must be quoted in the ORDER BY clause since they contain spaces.

Comment: Yeah, wrong column name, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of column 2 try `` `column 2` ``. Add backticks around the column names.

Comment: Thanks couldn't figure out how to add the backticks in the formatter

Answer (score 1):

Probably should be:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Tilmeldinger 
(column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
VALUES ($navn, $køn, $alder, $vægt, $bælte)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I removed the blank between "column" and the digit (like **column2** instead of **column 2**.  Same basic answer as the other folks.

Comment: I could see that, my point is that your answer should include an explanation of what you changed. Code only answer aren't always helpfully to beginners.

Answer (score 0):

as Your error says

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column 2, column 3, column 4, column 5, column 6) VALUES (Casper, mand, 20til25,' at line 2
```

--> **near** 'column 2, column 3, column 4, column 5, column 6) VALUES (Casper, mand, 20til25,' **at line 2**

i would guess, that the problem is, that You didn't escape the column names into '-characters, like `'column n'`

give it a try...